# Not reducing Trig Functions to zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

How do I tell *Mathematica* to reduce trig functions to zero when their arguments are integer multiples of pi or 2pi? I have this:

```
ψn[x_] := Sqrt[2/a] Sin[(n*Pi*x)/a]

ψl[x_] := Sqrt[2/a] Sin[(l*Pi*x)/a]

Ψbos[x1_,x2_] := (1/Sqrt[2]) (ψn[x1]*ψl[x2] + ψn[x2]*ψl[x1])

Simplify[Integrate[Ψbos[x1, x2]^2*x1^2, {x1, -a, a}], 
  Assuming l ∈ \[DoubleStruckCapitalZ] && n ∈ \[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]]
```

When *Mathematica* finishes this calculation I ran the result through a `FullSimplify` with same assumptions, but it still gave me terms that should be 0. E.g. there are still terms which involve `Sin[2*l*Pi]` or `Cos[n*Pi]` and I don't know how to get Mathematica to make them zero.

Comment: I think you want `Simplify[expr, Assumptions->...]`.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Check [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html). You probably mean `Simplify[Integrate[Ψbos[x1, x2]^2*x1^2, {x1, -a, a}], 
 l ∈ Integers && n ∈ Integers]`.